# glusterfs snapshot creation error

Tags: filesystems, glusterfs

I want to create a snapshot from glusterfs volume
the below command was written in glusterfs website

```
#snapshot create <snapname> <volname(s)> [description <description>] [force]
snapshot create s gv0
```

but the below error occurred:

```
snapshot: command not found
```

It means that I have to downlod glusterfs snapshot application, but I don't know if I have understood the problem correctly and how to download it.

Another question is that is this snapshot creates a human readable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the keyword gluster before issuing the command:

```
gluster snapshot create snap1 gv0
```

Go through the [documentation](https://gluster.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Managing%20Snapshots/) for more information. If you have more questions, feel free to ask on the gluster-users mailing list.